# Exchange server listening on port 25 but clients dont recieve emails

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook, windows-sbs-2008, outlook-web-app

My exchange server is listening on port 25, that is I can telnet into it and send an email but Outlook 2010/2007, OWA, and ActiveSync are not pulling down emails.

Outlook 2010 specifically says Connected To Exchange Server and Updating Inbox but it never updates the inbox. Also, OWA shows some of the newer mail messages, but when I double click on one to open it up in OWA, it times out.

Any idea what could be causing this? Also Exchange Transport and Information Store are started.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does outlook report "Folder up to date" at any point or just continually "Updating "?

If you are sending from one mailbox to another on the same server, SMTP shouldn't be an issue. It is possible that you have a large email in your outbox that is taking a long time to send and the Inbox update is waiting on the "send" to complete.

I've seen this a few times when services get hung up in exchange.  Most notably when the drive nears being full and the Information store stops responding instead of simply shutting down.

FWIW, I have used SBS in a few places (2003 and 2011), both work great in small deployments.

Comment: It continually says Updating Inbox without ever pulling down the new emails. When I go to send an email in outlook it does the Send/Receive screen with the green progress bar but doesn't finish and send. Maybe I should look into SBS again/more, I just heard that opinion over and over from co-workers. The drive has over 400 GB free so I don't think drive space is the issue but something isn't working...

Comment: Is there anything in your outbox?  My users love to stump me with this one after trying to send a 30MB attachment from their laptop on 3G while on a moving train. <sigh> If something is stuck in your outbox it will prevent new mail from coming in. 

Does the new mail show up in webmail?
Is it just your mailbox or others too?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Exchange?

Have a look in the tracking logs in the Exchange Management Console (depending on version).

I'm thinking possibly recipient policy but without more details we just don't know.

Comment: Exchange 2007 as a component of Small Business Server 2008 (SBS isn't the best. Poor choice I made when I was younger.) Thanks for the heads up about tracking logs

Comment: Nothing that wrong with SBS. For small businesses it works a treat, and its certainly a lot cheaper in terms of licenses. Just have to make sure you give it enough resource. SBS2011 now needs minimum 12GB RAM and more if you have more users..